# iCloud Key-Value storage does not work for users with full iCloud

Tags: flutter, key-value, icloud, cloudkit, key-value-store

I have a flutter app I developed and some of the users cannot use our backup system which uses iCloud Key-Value storage. These users all have one thing in common. Full iCloud. If they turn off the app from iCloud from backup details page in iCloud settings then it works. But if their iCloud is 100% full and they can't even access the page then it does not work.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? My app is made in flutter. It uses this package: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_kit.

Thanks.